# if statement with calculation

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am trying to do a sum calculation with an if condition. However I do not seem to get it right. I would like to do the following with the following table:

```
id   amt1   amt2
1     100     50
2      80    -50
3      40     30
4      45     50
5      85     20
```

I would like to `Sum(amt1)+(amt2)` only if `amt2<0` 
So the totals should be:

```
100
30
40
45
85
```

Is there any way of doing this in a query?

Kind regards,

Michel

Comment: You have no `if` condition errors and you have no MySQL errors in your posted code. In fact all you've posted is HTML which doesn't really help. It'd be similar to me asking a mechanic what's wrong with my car by showing him a picture of the engine.

Comment: @h2ooooooo More like asking what's wrong with your car by showing a picture of your bicycle.

Comment: sorry if it's not clear.. am struggling to format even the text in my question :) however I think the question is clear now, I have delted the code which was only there because I wanted format my table. Anyway do you understand what I mean with the question. I want to add two values but only add the second value if the amount is negative.

Comment: I formatted your post a bit. You will see it when someone has approved it. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting. No big deal. Most important thing is: indent code by four spaces and it will render with those gray boxes you frequently see. There's even a `{}` button for _format as code_ when editing.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, false == 0 and true == 1, so:

```
select amt1 + (amt2 < 0) * amt2
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Query :

```
SELECT IF(amt<0,SUM(amt1+amt2),amt1) as totals from tb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can do the following:

```
SELECT id, IF(amt2 < 0,sum(amt1 + amt2),amt1) as result FROM tb GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: You are welcome, please Upvote / mark as answered. So other people who see this question know what is the right answer. Thank you